# api response arrives after canActivate method is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, api, authorization

I'm really noob in angular.
I've written a guard service in order that only authorized (logged in) users be able to access specific components.
I'm using asp.net for back-end, I've an api in server side to return the Authorized status the method is async.
the problem is that sometimes the api response arrives after canActivate method is called so the method returns false although user is authorized.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuardService implements CanActivate {
  isSignedIn: boolean = false;
  result: Object;
  constructor(private router: Router,private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private url: string) {
    this.http.get(this.url + 'api/Authentication/UserInfo').subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result != null) {
          this.isSignedIn = true;
        }
      }
    )
  }
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (!this.isSignedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
    }
    return this.isSignedIn;
  }
}
```

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserInfo()
        {
            var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return Json(new
            {
                email = user.Email,
                name = user.FirstName,
                family = user.LastName
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

canActivate accept a boolean or an observable of boolean, avoid subscription 
try this

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{

return this.http.get(this.url + 'api/Authentication/UserInfo').pipe(map(
  (result) => {
    if (result != null) {
       return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
        return false;
     }
  }
 ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call authorization api from canActivate and Promise which returns true or false can be returned from canActivate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is a race condition between the API call and the evaluation of the `isSignedIn` variable. We can sort this out.

If you look at the [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) for the `CanActivate` Guard you will see that an `Observable<boolean>` is one of the possible return types. So delete the `HTTP` code in the constructor, change your method return type to `Observable<boolean>` and instead of returning the `isSignedIn` variable as you have done, do the following:

If your API call returns a boolean directly:

`return this.http.get(this.url + 'api/Authentication/UserInfo');`

If, for some reason your API does **not** return a boolean directly:

```
return this.http
           .get(this.url + 'api/Authentication/UserInfo')
           .pipe(result => !!result);
```

By returning an `Observable<boolean>` back, we are telling Angular that we will *at some point* return a boolean, but we just don't know *exactly when* that will happen. So in this case, it will wait until it resolves before continuing.